# Is it possible to print PowerPoint slides with themes?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I'm printing out a PowerPoint 2010 presentation to accompany the slide show. I'm noticing that none of the printed slides include the custom theme I made, creating a lot of extra white space around the edges. I tried changing it to a built in theme and it still does not print off. The theme is also missing in print preview.

I can't seem to find any information on getting themes to print. This doesn't even seem to be an issue given the lack of information I pulled up on Google. Is it possible to print slides with themes on them from PowerPoint? Are there any settings that I missed that should have been obvious?

**Note:**
Please ignore the fact that this is the worst possible way to have a hand out accompany a presentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found this to be dependent on the printer chosen. When I choose a color printer, there isn't a problem printing the theme. If I try it on a black & white printer it automatically removes the theme in order to print in grayscale.

In the past I have saved it as a PDF and then printed it to get the theme in a black & white printer.

Comment: I didn't even think of that. Immediately when I switched it to color the theme started printing. Ultimately I had already converted it to PDF to get around the issue, but I was curious about printing from PowerPoint. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Quite likely you haven't turned on printing of background images, which is stupidly off by default. Should be in tools->options

Comment: The box is currently unchecked.

Comment: ...background graphics printing checkbox should be checked

Comment: I imagine you're talking about an older version of PowerPoint since the Tools menu was replaced with the ribbon. The initial information I found was that the "Hide Background Image" box on the Design ribbon needed to be unchecked, which it was. There is nothing in the Options->Advanced tab that relates to images during printing, which is the only place I can find any references to printing in the Options menu. If you could provide a screenshot of where you found this, I'd happily try it, but as of right now, I can't find the box you mentioned since Tools no longer exists.

Comment: In 2010 it's Format->Background, uncheck Omit background graphics from master. If it's not that, ignore me ;)